# Can someone explain the generative and discriminative models in simple language?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, generative-models

Can someone explain the meaning of generative and discriminative and the difference between them in simple language? I have watched few videos on this subject on YouTube but could not able to understand the meaning. If you can explain them in simple language, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding

Generative: probability of x and y (eg, hmm)

Discriminative: probability of y given x (eg, logistic regression aka crf)

In the first, we can generate a new x and y, since we know their joint distribution

In the second, x is fixed, so we could not generate a new case

Example:  age and height.  The joint probability of age and height would allow you to draw a sample.  For example, (44, 2 ft) has low probability but (44,6 ft) higher.

A discriminative model would merely tell you height given some age.  The probability of 6 ft given 44 is higher than probability 2 ft given 44, but you don't know anything about the distribution of the ages or the distribution of ages and heights together, so you cannot generate a new case